# Vector: Finding the Sum Force

Tags: vectors

Suppose an object moving in the direction $3i + 2j$ is acted on by a force given by
the vector $4i+5j$. Express this force as a sum of a force in the direction of motion and
a force perpendicular to the direction of motion.

The answer should be $F=(\frac{66}{13}i + \frac{44}{13}j) + (-\frac{14}{13}i + \frac{21}{13}j)$

I started by finding the orthogonal projection of $4i+5j$ on $3i+2j$, and it is equal to $(\frac{66}{13}i + \frac{44}{13}j)$. So that it the first part (which is the force perpendicular to the motion, right?), how do I find the second part?

Comment: The vector sum of the parts must be the original force. So if you got one part, just subtract to get the other.

Comment: Second Part in parallel to $3i+2j$ that may be $2i-3j$!.

Comment: Meanwhile Denominator must be $\sqrt{13}$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The force must be broken into components in the direction of motion and perpendicular the direction of motion. $\overrightarrow{F} = \overrightarrow{F_\bot}+ \overrightarrow{F_{||}}$ and you have found $\overrightarrow{F_\bot}$